# Filter and return first matching element in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have the following account list look like this

```
val accountList = listOf(
    CustomerAccount(
        name = NameResponse(
            id = "4444444",
            lastName = "Smith",
            firstName = "John"
        ),
        addresses = listOf(
            HomeAddress(
                id = "123",
                zip = "33904",
                city = "Cape Coral",
                state = "FL",
                addressLine1 = "7544 Rockville Circle,"
            ),HomeAddress(
                id = "456",
                zip = "02360",
                city = "Plymouth",
                state = "MA",
                addressLine1 = "7967 Summit Ave,"
            ),HomeAddress(
                id = "123",
                zip = "33904",
                city = "Cape Coral",
                state = "FL",
                addressLine1 = "7544 Rockville Circle,"
            )
        )
    )
```

I'm trying to filter and find/return the first HomeAddress where HomeAddress id is 123.
So far I tried something like

```
accountList.filter { customerAccount ->
   customerAccount.addresses.first { homeAddress ->
      homeAddress.id.equals("123")  
   }
}
```

but it is not working, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you mean`accountList.flatMap { it.addresses }.first { it.id == "123" }`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the result you want from this. It's not clear if you want a filtered list of `CustomerAccount` objects or 1 particular `HomeAddress` object

Comment: @Phil I want to return HomeAddress with id 123

Comment: Sounds like @Sweeper's code in the first comment is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on the code you were trying - if you have many `CustomerAccount`'s and wanted to get the **first address of each account** which has `id = 123`, then use `map` instead of `filter` at the top-level:

```
accountList.map { customerAccount ->
    customerAccount.addresses.first { homeAddress ->
        homeAddress.id == "123"
    }
}
```

2. If there are customers who have no address with `id = 123`, then use `null`s and change the inner function from `first` to `firstOrNull`.

```
accountList.map { customerAccount ->
    customerAccount.addresses.firstOrNull { homeAddress ->
        homeAddress.id == "123"
    }
}
```

3. If you only want the first address of each customer with `id = 123` and skip any customers who have no address like that, then use `mapNotNull` at the top-level.

```
accountList.mapNotNull { customerAccount ->
    customerAccount.addresses.firstOrNull { homeAddress ->
        homeAddress.id == "123"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get all the home addresses as a single `List<HomeAddresses>` first, and then use `first` to filter. Note that you don't need `filter` - `first` itself does filtering.

```
accountList
    // flatMap "flattens" the many lists of addresses, and gives you a List<HomeAddress>
    .flatMap { it.addresses }
    .first { it.id == "123" }
```

If you have many `CustomerAccounts` and each customer has many `HomeAddress`es, consider adding `.asSequence()` before `.flatMap` to do the flat-mapping lazily.